# biodegradable hair gel?

Tags: biodegradable-waste

I'll be spending a month this summer on a mountain in an earth-friendly community. In their welcoming documents it says: `[we] will provide bio-degradable soap, shampoo and lotion. When packing any additional toiletries, please bring biodegradable products only.`

My hair looks awful without some kind of styling product. Can anyone recommend a men's hair gel that will biodegrade?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! I've placed your question on hold, because it is asking for product recommendations and answers to such questions tend to be rather subjective. Could you please edit your question and change it into something that can be answered more objectively? E.g. something like "do biodegradable hair gels exist and if so which one is the most environmentally friendly?"

Comment: BTW, a quick google on "biodegradable hair gel" revealed 2 products that claim to be biodegradable: [Aubrey Organics Mens Ginseng and Biotin Hair Gel](http://www.green-store.biz/shops/index.php?proddb=29&pid=343) and [Head Organics - Extra Hold Hair gel](http://www.luckyvitamin.com/p-22043-head-organics-extra-hold-hair-gel-845-oz)